# @SpringBootApplication does not load static files

Tags: javascript, css, image, static, spring-boot

The static files are located under:

```
src/main/resources/static/
```

- js
- css
- img
- etc..

No matter what I do the files never get picked up. I've tried addResourceHandlers but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You should post a bit more information. E.g. how do you access those resources? Are there any log messages? If possible, show some code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by removing @EnableWebMvcSecurity as it was clashing with @SpringBootApplication.  When you use the EnableWebMvcSecurity annotation spring expects your static files under webapps/resources rather than resources/static.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the static contents should be in the webcontent/static folder and then try doing something as below, the below code is used to map the static resources and the u can access them in the .jsp or .html file you have...

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/static/" />
```

the above will go in the dispatcher-servlet.xml, and the below in you jsp or templated page you have.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'/>" />
```